# How to solve Pair sum Problem in python with time complexity of O(nlogn) or O(n)?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

Pair sum in array

Given a random integer array A and a number x. Find and print the pair of elements in the array which sum to x.
Array A can contain duplicate elements.
While printing a pair, print the smaller element first.
That is, if a valid pair is (6, 5) print "5 6". There is no constraint that out of 5 pairs which have to be printed in 1st line. You can print pairs in any order, just be careful about the order of elements in a pair.

Input format :
Line 1 : Integer N (Array size)
Line 2 : Array elements (separated by space)
Line 3 : Integer x

Output format :
Line 1 : Pair 1 elements (separated by space)
Line 2 : Pair 2 elements (separated by space)
Line 3 : and so on

Constraints :
1 <= N <= 1000
1 <= x <= 100

Sample Input:

```
9
1 3 6 2 5 4 3 2 4
7
```

Sample Output:

```
(1 6)
(3 4)
(3 4)
(2 5)
(2 5)
(3 4)
(3 4)
```

My approach::
 1.Take 2 pointers/markers start and end
 pointing to first and last element of the array respectively:
 2. sort the array -o(nlogn) 
 3.while start < end 
    check the sum using start and end pointers 
    If the sum by pointers is greater than actual sum decrease the end pointer from to end-1 and if it's smaller increase the start pointer to start+1.

code:

```
def pairSum(arr, x):
    arr.sort()  # nlogn
    i = 0
    j = len(arr) - 1

    while i < j:
        if arr[i] + arr[j] > x:
            j -= 1

        elif arr[i] + arr[j] < x:
            i += 1

        else:  # got the match  arr[i] +arr[j] ==x
            if arr[i] <= arr[j]:
                print(arr[i], arr[j])

                if arr[j - 1] == arr[j]:
                    j -= 1

                elif arr[i + 1] == arr[i]:
                    i += 1
                else:
                   i += 1
                   j -= 1

            else:
                print(arr[j], arr[i])
                if arr[i + 1] == arr[i]:
                    i += 1
                elif arr[j - 1] == arr[j]:
                    j -= 1
                else:
                    i += 1
                    j -= 1
```

I have tried this problem and it is working fine for unique element, but failing for duplicates elements and it is because while loop it terminating early.
Kindly share your thoughts :)

Comment: What about sharing your code so that we can suggest how to improve that?

Comment: @Cheerag Verma Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. Questions that seam like someone is asking "Please do my homework for me..." are usually not very well received. In your case you say you have a solution that fails for certain conditions. Please share this solution and the error you get for cases with duplicates and we may help you find the problem. However like this it is hard to help you without starting from scratch. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how people ask questions most effectively.

Comment: Thanks @Chris for the guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

First:
Once you sorted the array and you have `while i < j:` it means that in the first `else:` the condition `if arr[i] <= arr[j]:` is always true, so I would just simplify it.

Second:
Your problem is when you have `arr[i + 1] == arr[i]` and `arr[j - 1] == arr[j]`. In your implementation, in this case, you will  decrement the j value causing the loss of a pair, so i would create an if for this condition.

Possible correction:

```py
#...
        else:  # got the match  arr[i] +arr[j] ==x
            print(arr[i], arr[j])

            if arr[j - 1] == arr[j] and arr[i + 1] == arr[i]:
                print(arr[i], arr[j])
                print(arr[i], arr[j])
                i += 1
                j -= 1

            elif arr[j - 1] == arr[j]:
                j -= 1

            elif arr[i + 1] == arr[i]:
                i += 1

            else:
                i += 1
                j -= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

For O(n) complexity you can use a dictionary to collect the numbers that correspond to a matching sum (i.e. target-n) and access it directly as you progress through the list:

```
numbers = [1, 3, 6, 2, 5, 4, 3, 2, 4]
target  = 7

matches = dict()
for n in numbers:
    for m in matches.get(n,[]):
        print(f"{n} {m}" if n<m else f"{m} {n}")
    matches.setdefault(target-n,[]).append(n)
```

output:

```
1 6
2 5
3 4
3 4
2 5
3 4
3 4
```

*note that when there are duplicates in the list, it is not actually possible to perfectly achieve O(n) because the number of results to print could be exponentially > n*